# matplotlib - how to change axis labels base exponent

Tags: python, matplotlib

Reasonably new to python and I have some code like this

```
V = [0, 0.003, 0, 0.0002]   
pylab.axis(V)
legend_font_props = FontProperties()
legend_font_props.set_size('small')
pylab.xlabel('Time (ms)')

pylab.xticks(rotation=45)
pylab.xticks.set_major_formatter(FixedOrderFormatter(-3))

pylab.ylabel('Current (A)')
pylab.title('Title')        
pylab.plot(Temp0_Xvals, Temp0_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp10_Xvals, Temp10_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp20_Xvals, Temp20_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp30_Xvals, Temp30_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp40_Xvals, Temp40_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp50_Xvals, Temp50_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp60_Xvals, Temp60_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp70_Xvals, Temp70_Yvals, marker='+')
pylab.plot(Temp80_Xvals, Temp80_Yvals, marker='+')

pylab.show()
```

I want to change the base exponent of my x labels because they take to much space and will look better smaller where I just add the units into the x axis title. I found some code that does exaclty what I want below

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedOrderFormatter(-9))

plt.show()
```

Obviously they are using a different format to how I'm attempting to do it, and I can't find a way to convert the ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedOrderFormatter(-9)) into my code.

Is there any way to do what I want without rewriting my code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to get the current axes object using the `pylab` interface?

It's just:

```
ax = pylab.gca()
```

However, I'd *strongly* recommend switching away from using the `pylab` interface. It's really only meant for interactive use.  At the very least, switch to using `matplotlib.pyplot` instead of `pylab`. `pylab` is a *huge* namespace. It's easier to work with `numpy` and `matplotlib` separately instead of rolling them into the same namespace.